# Calculate Linear regression on data set in Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Say I have a input as follows:

```
60,3.1

61,3.6 

62,3.8 

63,4 

65,4.1
```

Ouput is expected as follows:

Expected output: y = -8.098 + 0.19x.

I know how to do this in java. But don't know how this work with mapreduce model. Can any one give idea or sample Map Reduce code on this problem? I will appreciate this.

This simple mathematical example:

```
Regression Formula:
Regression Equation(y) = a + bx 
Slope(b) = (NΣXY - (ΣX)(ΣY)) / (NΣX2 - (ΣX)2)
Intercept(a) = (ΣY - b(ΣX)) / N

where 
              x and y are the variables.
              b = The slope of the regression line 
              a = The intercept point of the regression line and the y axis. 
              N = Number of values or elements 
              X = First Score
              Y = Second Score
              ΣXY = Sum of the product of first and Second Scores
              ΣX = Sum of First Scores
              ΣY = Sum of Second Scores
              ΣX2 = Sum of square First Scores
```

e.g.

```
X Values   Y Values 
  60          3.1 
  61          3.6 
  62          3.8 
  63            4 
  65          4.1
```

To find regression equation, we will first find slope, intercept and use it to form regression equation..

```
Step 1: Count the number of values.
            N = 5

  Step 2: Find XY, X2
            See the below table

X Value   Y Value          X*Y             X*X 
  60        3.1     60 * 3.1 = 186     60 * 60 = 3600 
  61        3.6     61 * 3.6 = 219.6   61 * 61 = 3721 
  62        3.8     62 * 3.8 = 235.6   62 * 62 = 3844 
  63          4     63 * 4 = 252       63 * 63 = 3969 
  65        4.1     65 * 4.1 = 266.5   65 * 65 = 4225 



  Step 3: Find ΣX, ΣY, ΣXY, ΣX2.
            ΣX = 311 
            ΣY = 18.6 
            ΣXY = 1159.7 
            ΣX2 = 19359 

  Step 4: Substitute in the above slope formula given.
            Slope(b) = (NΣXY - (ΣX)(ΣY)) / (NΣX2 - (ΣX)2)
            = ((5)*(1159.7)-(311)*(18.6))/((5)*(19359)-(311)2)
            = (5798.5 - 5784.6)/(96795 - 96721)
            = 13.9/74
            = 0.19 

  Step 5: Now, again substitute in the above intercept formula given.
            Intercept(a) = (ΣY - b(ΣX)) / N 
            = (18.6 - 0.19(311))/5
            = (18.6 - 59.09)/5
            = -40.49/5
            = -8.098

  Step 6: Then substitute these values in regression equation formula
            Regression Equation(y) = a + bx 
            = -8.098 + 0.19x.
```

Suppose if we want to know the approximate y value for the variable x = 64. Then we can substitute the value in the above equation.

```
    Regression Equation(y) = a + bx 
    = -8.098 + 0.19(64).
    = -8.098 + 12.16
    = 4.06
```

Comment: I've found [this](http://nerdslearning.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/building-linear-regression-with-mapreduce-on-hadoop/) by googling. Since linear regression is a common task with hadoop there are lots of resources about it.

Comment: Can you suggest any good resource which help me.

Comment: http://nerdslearning.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/building-linear-regression-with-mapreduce-on-hadoop/

Comment: I've already seen this implementation. This is different type of implementation. any other similar to my question.

Comment: LinkedIn's DataFu library has an example: http://engineering.linkedin.com/datafu/datafu-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded Map-Reduce implementation of linear regression with mrjob here:

https://github.com/AmazaspShumik/MapReduce-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Linear%20Regression%20MapReduce/LinearRegressionTS.py

Two most important components for getting parameters of linear regression
are X.t*X (where X is input matrix where each row is observation) and 
X.t * Y.
Each Mapper calculates X_i.t * X_i and X_i.t * Y_i for i-th part of data that it processes, then all mappers output data to single reducer. Reducer sum results of all mappers:
X.t * X = Σi (X_i.t * X_i) 
X.t * Y = Σi (X_i.t * Y_i)

Then parameter vector b = (X.t * X)^-1 *  X.t * Y
However better solution for parameter identification will be to use Cholesky decomposition as it is done in code.